# Getting Transport error while importing android project from GIT

Tags: android, github

[image: Error screenshot]

I am trying to import android project from eclipse using GIT earlier it was working fine now i am getting Transport error for all project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this is not related to android, 
If you have proper internet connection, Just check weather you uploaded your public key to your GIT account, If you have created ssh key already, they should be available in C:\Users\Your_User.ssh (in Windows environment)
If they are not available, you need to create keys and need to upload public key to your GIT account.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like git is looking for an ssl certificate and refusing to function without it. A good fix to make the problem go away and stay away: Window --> Preferences --> Team --> Git --> Configuration --> New Entry --> http.sslverify=false.

That should take care of it.